# Rendering an array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render my `arr` in my render function.The code doesn't give any  error.Here I'm trying to calculate the fibonacci series and display it on the screen.The problem with the code is when I enter a certain number in the text field it doesn't print the series on the screen but when I clear the text field without refreshing it prints the correct series on the screen.I can't understand where this error comes from.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(1);
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);

  function handleGenerateFibonacci(event) {
    for (const n of generator(limit)) {
      arr.push(n)
      setArr(arr)
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  function* generator(limit) {
    var i = 0;
    var a = 0;
    var b = 1;
    yield a;
    yield b;
    for (i = 1; i <= limit - 1; i++) {
      var fibNumber = a + b
      yield fibNumber
      a = b
      b = fibNumber
    }
  }



  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form >
        <h1>Generating the Fibonacci Series</h1>
        <h2>Enter the range</h2>
        <TextField onChange={e => setLimit(e.target.value)}></TextField>
        <br />
        <Button onClick={handleGenerateFibonacci} type="submit" style={{
          height: 40,
          width: 160,
          borderRadius: 10,
          backgroundColor: "Blue",
          marginLeft: 50,
          marginRight: 50,
          marginTop: 20,
          fontSize: 16,
          color: "white"
        }} >Calculate</Button>
        <br />
        <h2>Result:</h2>
        <div >
        <p>Fibonacci Series : {"[ " + arr + " ]"}</p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    
  );
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you click button your code doesn't change value itself, just content of value

```
function handleGenerateFibonacci(event) {
    for (const n of generator(limit)) {
      arr.push(n)
      setArr(arr)
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

...so system doesn't really know that your array has been changed, so better write it this way

```
function handleGenerateFibonacci(event) {
    for (const n of generator(limit)) {
      arr.push(n)
    }
    setArr([...arr])
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

PS when you clean the text field, limit property of state is correctly changing, so system refresh the components

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach,

```
function handleGenerateFibonacci(event) {
    for (const n of generator(limit)) {
      setArr((a) => [...a, n]);
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

working demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-mayer-xu91t?file=/src/App.js:270-423